# She does love me or She loves me?

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to  know  the difference between:

> **She does love me**

and

> **She loves me.**

Comment: They mean the same.  Just say "She loves me" unless you have some reason to use the other one.  For example, emphasis or contrast.  "She doesn't respect me, but she does love me."

Comment: What do you think the difference is?  What research have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both  are  correct  but in  a different  context.

Suppose  your   friend  told  you   :

> **she loves  me**

You may  ask:    **Does  she really   love  you**?

Then  you  say. **Yes. She  does  love me**

The  helping  verbs    **do**     **does**
  **did**   are   used   for  emphasis.

Comment: Covered, as one might expect, many years ago.

Comment: Thank you for reply, this used for fast answers or highlight the idea.